# Character Movement, Acceleration C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, acceleration

Hi everyone Newbie here.

Top-down Zelda style game.

I'm trying to figure out how to make my player build speed to max speed then reduce speed to stoping.

I already have movement with GetRawAxis but my char moves at max speed the moment I press move with this method.

```cs
private void PlayerMovement()
{
    var playerMovement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;

    transform.position = new Vector3(
        transform.position.x + playerMovement.x,
        transform.position.y + playerMovement.y,
        transform.position.z);
}
```

Comment: Please provide Code and/or more info

Comment: Instead of setting velocity, you could try using the RigidBody's `AddForce` in the direction of the stick, and add some drag to cause him to stop slowly if no force is being actively applied

Comment: Here's my current movement method

private void PlayerMovement()
    {
        var playerMovement = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;

        transform.position = new Vector3(
            transform.position.x + playerMovement.x,
            transform.position.y + playerMovement.y,
            transform.position.z);
    }

Comment: Sorry Don't know how to make the code look properly

Comment: So if I add force it creates drag at the beginning and the end of movement @Ahndwoo?

Comment: @Tas7e, did you figure it out?

Comment: @Tas7e Hey I saw the question you just deleted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67320573/jumping-with-no-change-direction-in-air
I was about to post an answer so here it is anyway hope it helps
https://pastebin.com/6ZRed1eu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [`Vector3.SmoothDamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html).

This uses a Vector storing the current "speed" and dumps it slowly.

Example can be found here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SmoothDamp.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is a scenario where you can move your object in the x axis, gradually increasing the speed. You can do the same with the slowing down. Gradually decrease the speed by a value.

```
float acceleration = 0.6;
float maxSpeed = 30;
float speed = 0;

void Update(){
   if(speed < maxSpeed){
      speed += acceleration * Time.deltaTime;
    }

   transform.position.x = transform.position.x + speed*Time.deltaTime;

}
```

Comment: 1) this only applies motion on the X axis 2) does not take into account player input and 3) doesn't include deceleration.

Comment: Yes I know it doesn’t do any of that but that’s the point. I’m just pointing him to the right direction. He can apply the logic to other scenarios.